# Django with jquery-fileupload ui throws error with "This field is required."

Tags: jquery, python, django, file-upload

I have a Django project features uploading file for analysis.
I reference and transplant the UI part from [sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload](https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload), specifically, the upload form and buttons, including the static css, js files and some of python scripts.

Everything was set, but it just keep telling me "This field is required." after "Start" button was clicked.

**views.py**

```
import json
from django.views.generic import CreateView, DeleteView, ListView
from django.views import View
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import File
from .response import JSONResponse, response_mimetype
from .serialize import serialize

class FileCreateView(CreateView):
    model = File
    fields = "__all__"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        files = [serialize(self.object)]
        data = {'files': files}
        response = JSONResponse(data, mimetype=response_mimetype(self.request))
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
        return response

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        data = json.dumps(form.errors)
        return HttpResponse(content=data, status=400, content_type='application/json')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="files")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('profiler-new', )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.file.name
        super(File, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """delete -- Remove to leave file."""
        self.file.delete(False)
        super(File, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import Example, FileCreateView, FileDeleteView, FileListView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^new/$', FileCreateView.as_view(), name='profile-new'),
...
```

**file_form.html**

```
...
<div class="container" style="width: 100%">
    <!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
    <form id="fileupload" action="{% url 'profile-new' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->

        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
...
```

And I modified the **main.js** as:

```
/* global $, window */

$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: '/profiler/new/'
    });
...
```

When I tested the upload function and the javascript widget works, I got `[]` from `request.FILES.getlist("files")` and got `form` as:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_file">File:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><input type="file" name="file" required id="id_file" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_slug">Slug:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="slug" maxlength="50" id="id_slug" /></td></tr>
```

Cloud anyone help me identify the key to the bug and suggest how to deal with it?

**Update 1**

I'v add the two parameters `blank=True, null=True` to the FileField and another exception was thrown: `ValueError: The 'file' attribute has no file associated with it.`

Answer (score 1):

put blank=True and null=True in the model for filefield

Comment: I'v add the two parameters to it and another exception was thrown:
'ValueError: The 'file' attribute has no file associated with it.'

Comment: first of all tell me, do you need the user to upload the files mandatorily? or the user might not upload it? depending on what you need the answer depends. so make it little clear that what you actually need

Comment: User have to upload files to trigger the analysis service and the analysis needs the uploaded files. What I want is to make the UI widget works and the server can receive the uploaded files properly.